# How to use multiple SQL database in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, azure-sql-database

We are trying to  SQL Azure Geo-Replication for load balancing 95% of SQL transaction are read only and 5% requires Write.

In SQL Azure Geo-replication we can have only One(aka Primary) database as RW and rest are RO. so we need to separate the RW and RO traffic. I was wondering that is there an easy way to use multiple connection string one for RW and one for RO.

Comment: SQL Azure Geo-Replication is a database level recovery solution, not to use it for multiple connections. In fact you should only connect on the primary database and have the SQL copies ready for migration if something goes wrong with your primary (main) database.

Comment: We are trying to implement a load balancing solution as documented on Azure website Design pattern 2: Active-active deployment for application load balancing. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-designing-cloud-solutions-for-disaster-recovery/#design-pattern-2-active-active-deployment-for-application-load-balancing

Comment: The only solution I can think of is to pass all your read only logic inside a tenant that connects to your read only database. It could act as a sub directory of your domain.

Comment: Cool thanks, makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a web app deployed for each replica as described in Pattern 2, you can create a round-robin TM profile (if replicas are in the same region) or performance profile (if replicas are in different regions). This way all connections to the TM endpoint will be routed accordingly. Since you have 5% writes, you should also create a failover profile with a different endpoint. The latter will route all connections to the same web app (and the primary db).  You can have up to 4 read-only replicas.